# MySQL Fulltext index search returns wrong results

Tags: mysql, search, indexing, fulltext-index

I have a MyISAM table with a Fulltext index on the `NAME` column which is `VARCHAR(200)`. I'm searching the table using the Boolean mode and I'm getting very strange results. Example: Let's look for records with the word "TRULY" in the NAME column:

`select * from table_MYISAM WHERE MATCH(NAME) AGAINST('+TRULY' IN BOOLEAN MODE);`

This returns no results. Now let's look for both "TRULY" and "RICHARD":

`select * from table_MYISAM WHERE MATCH(NAME) AGAINST('+TRULY +RICHARD' IN BOOLEAN MODE);`

This query returns hundreds of thousands of records with "RICHARD" in NAME, but none contain "TRULY". What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the list for [myisam stop words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-stopwords.html),`truly` is in there.Scroll further down.You can use an empty file if you dont want any stop words or edit the existing one.